# Исчезают элементы при использовании before

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, получается столкнулся с такой проблеммой, что когда пытаюсь сделать задний фон элеменнту как на сриншоте через before, у меня исчезает элемент `<i>`
Как это можно исправить и где я ошибся.

```css
.agency {
    background-color: #11749e;
    text-align: center;
}

.agency i {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.agency i:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 40px 60px;
}

.agency p {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <section class="agency">
        <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                        <h3>Feature one</h3>
                        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor </p>
                    </div>

                </div>


    </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.agency {
    background-color: #11749e;
    text-align: center;
}

.agency i {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.agency i:after  {
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 40px 60px;
}

.agency p {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <section class="agency">
        <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                        <h3>Feature one</h3>
                        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor </p>
                    </div>

                </div>


    </section>
```

В fa иконки через псевдоэлемент before сделаны.
Улучшенный код:

```css
.agency {
    background-color: #11749e;
    text-align: center;
}

.agency i {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.agency i:before {
    color:#fff;
}
.agency i div:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    left: calc(50% - 50px);

    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.2);
    border-radius: 100%;

}

.agency p {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <section class="agency">
        <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <i class="far fa-edit"><div></div></i>
                        <h3>Feature one</h3>
                        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor </p>
                    </div>

                </div>


    </section>
```